# No adapter attached; skipping layout error (with JSON prasing)

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I've done everything right but my logcat still shows this error  No adapter attached; skipping layout

I have tried setting an empty adapter first inside of onCreate() and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after I get the data in my praseJSON() but still no luck!

Everything in the Recycler adapter file is also set according to all the fix is found online.

```
private static final String TAG = "Nearby";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private NearbyAdapter mNearbyAdapter;
    private ArrayList<NearbyItem> mNearbyList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String apiURL = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewNearby);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNearbyAdapter);
        mNearbyAdapter = new NearbyAdapter(NearbyActivity.this, mNearbyList);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mNearbyList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseJSON();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }


private void parseJSON()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting parseJSON()"+TAG);
        String url = apiURL;
        Log.d(TAG,"URL: " + url);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("member");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject member = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String nName = "";
                                String nType = "";
                                String nDesc = "";
                                if (member.has("name")){
                                    nName = member.getString("name");
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Name is: " + nName);
                                }
                                if(member.has("type")) {
                                    nType = member.getString("type");
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Type is: " + nType);
                                }
                                if(member.has("description")){
                                    nDesc = member.getString("description");
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Desc is: " + nDesc);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    nDesc += nName;
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Desc is: " + nDesc);
                                }

                                if(nType.contains("bus_stop")){
                                    nType = "Bus Stop";

                                }
                                else if (nType.contains("train_station"))
                                {
                                    nType = "Train Station";
                                }
                                mNearbyList.add(new NearbyItem(nName, nType, nDesc));
                            }
                            mNearbyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mNearbyAdapter = new NearbyAdapter(NearbyActivity.this, mNearbyList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNearbyAdapter);

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29141729/6296561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've set the adapter `mNearbyAdapter` **before** creating the `NearbyAdapter` object.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewNearby);

        // you passed mNearbyAdapter here
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNearbyAdapter);  

        // but you created the object for it here
        mNearbyAdapter = new NearbyAdapter(NearbyActivity.this, mNearbyList);
        ...
```

To fix this, create the object for your adapter first, then call `setAdapter(mNearbyAdapter)`.